# Can't update php file via ajax $.post

Tags: php, jquery

I have this:

```
<div class="text_window"></div>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>Send</button>

$(function() {
    getStatus();
});

function getStatus() {

    $.post('update.php', function(data) {
        $('div.text_window').html(data);
    });
    setTimeout("getStatus()",1000);
}
```

update.php

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
if (!$text) $text = 'string';
echo $text;
```

Now, if I manually change the `$text` var and save the file, it will update in the browser accordingly, but I want to change it by putting text into the textarea and pressing the button.

I wrote the following function but nothing is returned.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    update();
});

function update() {
    var text = $('textarea').val();
    $.post('update.php',{text:text}, function(data) {
        alert ('ok');
    });
}
```

How can I update the '$text' variable from this page using the textarea and the button?

Comment: _Never, __ever___ pass a string to `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. The first argument should be a function reference: `setTimeout("getStatus()",1000);` <== __bad__ ==> `setTimeout(getStatus,1000);` <== __Good__

Comment: Let's try var_dump instead of echo
And see the network tab (if you are using chrome) for the request result

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the closing `)` and there is no echo function.

```
function update() {
    var text = $('textarea').val();

    $.post('update.php',{text:text}, function(data) {
       // echo 'ok';
       alert('ok');
       console.log('ok')
    }); // here
}
```

Comment: a lovely comment: //here XD

Comment: @fattomhk yeah, I wanted to make a big red arrow there but it didn't let me :/

Comment: typo here, in my code it is ok, i still have the same problem.

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm get rid of echo

Comment: Yeah, anyway it is still not updating.

Comment: @OlliccaMindstorm Use `alert('ok');` instead of `alert 'ok';` as it's shown in this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$.post('update.php',{text:text}, function(data) {
    echo 'ok';
});
```

Comment: I always do. My problem can be recreated on someone's machine in half a a minute.